# What are rawToValue and valueToRaw in Extjs pickerfield?

Tags: picker, extjs6-classic

I'm using Extjs 6.5. I want to implement a picker that have 4 fields: String, Number, Combobox, Color.

I want to save value as an object as follow:

```
{
   string: 'its my name',
   number: 12,
   combobox: 'combo',
   color: 'ffffffff'
}
```

That means when you call `field.getValue()` it return above object, but In field textfield only `string` value is shown. User can expand picker and edit some fields. I can't understand whats `rawToValue` and `valueToRaw` in `Ext.form.field.picker`? What are these?

Answer (score 0):

> Basically [picker](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Picker.html#method-createPicker) is extend from [field](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Base.html) and this field have both methods valueToRaw & rawToValue

Hierarchy of extend of **picker** you can see here [ExtJs pickerfield](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Picker.html#method-createPicker)

- [rawTovalue](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Base.html#method-rawToValue) converts a raw input field value into a mixed-type value that is suitable for this particular field type. This allows controlling the normalization and conversion of user-entered values into field-type-appropriate values, e.g. a Date object for [Ext.form.field.Date](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html), and is invoked by getValue.
  It is up to individual implementations to decide how to handle raw values that cannot be successfully converted to the desired object type.
- [valueToRaw](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Base.html#method-valueToRaw) converts a mixed-type value to a raw representation suitable for displaying in the field. This allows controlling how value objects passed to setValue are shown to the user, including localization. For instance, for a [Ext.form.field.Date](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html), this would control how a Date object passed to setValue would be converted to a String for display in the field.